# Changing the access database on the server

Tags: ms-access

So I have this access database on a 2003 SQL Server and I recently changed a report in it on the server, but on the user end the report is not changed. 
Do I have to do some sort of update in order to see the recent version of the report?

Comment: I think you need to explain better. SQL Server does not contain access databases. There is no 2003 version of SQL Server. The next version after 2000 is 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that you updated an access database on a 2003 SQL server so that leads me to believe that you have an .accdb or .mdb file on the server that you editted.  It would seem that your users have a copy of the same .accdb or .mdb file on their computer.  Therefore the user's need to obtain a new copy of the .accdb or .mdb file that you modified on the server.